# Join query in Python between list object and tablename in database in a simple way

Tags: python, list, join

I have a list:

```
[(1,'otherfield1'),(3,'otherfield3')]
```

And a table named department_user in database:

```
|---ID----name-----department------manager---|
----------------------------------------------
|   1   | name1  |  department1 |  manager1  |
----------------------------------------------
|   2   | name2  |  department2 |  manager2  |
----------------------------------------------
|   3   | name3  |  department3 |  manager3  |
..............
...........
```

I want to "left join" the list and the rows in the table to get the  result below:

```
[[1, 'name1', 'dep1', 'mgr1', 'otherfield1'], [3, 'name3', 'dep3', 'mgr3', 'otherfield3']]
```

I know that I can get the rowcollection using an SQL query 'in (....)' first and then combine the result with the list to build what I want.

But, is there a simple way to do this?

I am new to Python and found a very useful method weeks ago:

```
c.executemany(''' INSERT INTO entry (id, title) VALUES(?,?);'''
                  ,[(item.id,item.title)for item in entryList]
              )
```

This API can do the "insert" between a database table and a Python list. So, I think there maybe a similar API on "join" like this:

```
resultlist=cursor.leftjoin("select id,title from entry where ....",[(1,"author1"),(2,"author2")....])

resultlist>>>[(1,'title1','author1'),(2,'title2','author2')]
```

Comment: the mainpoint is this: can i do "left jon" between a python list  object and  a datatable in mysql database  in  a single code?

Comment: That depends on which MySQL interface you plan on using. Are you using `MySQLdb`? `SQLAlchemy` perhaps?

Comment: mysql connector/python.   import mysql.connector

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if you are looking for this, but might help:

```
>>> otherfield=[(1,'otherfield1'),(3,'otherfield3')]
>>> mylist = [[1,'name1','dep1','mgr1'],[3,'name3','dep3','mgr3']]
>>> mydict = dict(otherfield)
>>> for row in mylist:
    row+=[mydict[row[0]]]


>>> mylist
[[1, 'name1', 'dep1', 'mgr1', 'otherfield1'], [3, 'name3', 'dep3', 'mgr3', 'otherfield3']]
>>>
```

Comment: not exactly. the "mylist" in your code should be  a table in mysql database, not a python list object.  it is the normal way,

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question. If you are fetching data from mysql table then it should be a cursor object and you can easily get the python list using fetchall. Probably a sample of you python code on what you have tried till now will help.